# How to read out the data in HTC Desire SMS backup file?

Tags: sms, htc-desire, backup, data-recovery

Unfortunately my HTC Desire SMS app crashed (HTC official android 2.2), all SMS and MMS were lost. When I tried to recover from a previously backed up SMS file (generated by Desire SMS app), but it didn't work, prompting failed to recover. But I found actually most of SMS and MMS had been recovered, with some important ones still missing. I want to open the backup file directly to read out the missed SMS, how to do it? Someone said the backup file is SQLite file, right?

Answer (score 2):

All the messages in Android are stored in an SQlite database on the mobile. So, I guess this Desire backup application simply copies this database to an accessible folder (presumably sdcard).
Since it's an SQLite file, you can simply download and use an [SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) and view the SMS in there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The SMS backup file is stored in /mnt/sdcard/sms_backup folder. I copied it to my PC(Windows 7) and tried to load with SQLite3. With .schema command, it prompted an error: file is encrypted or is not a database. Seems not work.

Comment: you can try decrypting the file, in that case. Though I doubt if that will certainly help. You can use one of the following: [SQLiteCrypt API](http://sqlite-crypt.com/documentation.htm), or [SQLite Encryption Ext.](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) or [SQLite CEROD](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/cerod.html). Again, do create a copy of the file before applying these techniques

Comment: I tried SQLiteCrypt, the problem is I don't know the encrypt password. If I tried changing password by .changepass, it does not work either. I had made a new SMS backup file with the same method, which can be restored by HTC Desire correctly. However, the new file can not be opened with SQLite3 or SQLiteCrypt. I guess HTC had changed something of the backup file.

Comment: either that, or it's a different file altogether.

Comment: Yes, agree. Don't know whether anybody had ever read out the contents of SMS backup file successfully?

Comment: A standard SQLite header should begin with "SQLite format 3" or contain "SQLenc" if encrypted. I checked the file and it's not the case.

Answer (score -1):

Try the unix `strings` command against the db file directly. This will search the binary db file for human readable strings and print them on the console.